# Linux - how to swap each other content of two partitions?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

I have a problem. I installed ubuntu on hdd, and mount one of ssd partition to /home. Hdd partition=20Gb (full in 40%), ssd partition=60Gb (full in 5%). Can I move a hdd partition to ssd and a ssd partition to hdd? I have windows files in these partitions on the disks. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

No, not as in telling the system to swap the files on each disk.

Quickest method is likely:

1. make a backup of your personal files.
2. reinstall.
3. restore the backup.

> I have a problem. I installed ubuntu on hdd, and mount one of ssd partition to /home.

Why is that a problem? You have the directory that requires the most space (/home) already on the largest disk and 20Gb for the base desktop system (so without /home is more than enough) (a server would be different).

Your problem is not fixed by swapping. Your problem is likely to return quickly: 20+60Gb is not a lot if you want to keep large files, like HD video. 1/2 hour is roughly 1Gb when I check my anime episodes. Consider removing files or storing them outside those disk (USB, online) or getting a larger hard disk. 500Gb internal is less than 50 USD/EUR.

The only thing wrong about your setup: I would put the OS on the SSD but only because it speeds things up; not because you store your personal files on it.